# Two android apps with same logic but different styles

Tags: android

I have two Android apps with different icon and color themes but that share the same activities, layout and logic. Any idea how to manage these apps? It would be counter-productive to duplicate the logic and layouts. There should be only one instance of layout, logic, etc.

Comment: I know abt library project my question is i have a app which takes the drawables and colors from other app and display the content. So app1 have the logic layout etc, app2 and app3 have only drawables and colors. app2 and app3 depends on app1. app1 dont have ui it should run in backgroud .

Comment: Yes, and this is what library projects are for. The only thing of note that you will need to do is produce empty placeholder images and colours in the library project (app1), such that it compiles. You can then override those resources with the ones you define in the applications (app2 and app3).

Answer (score 3):

this is the perfect scenario for using an [Android library project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject).

Use your project as library (check the properties) and let the two implementing projects use that library.

Answer (score 2):

You can re-use code and resources like layouts, images etc. across multiple applications using a [library project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject), linked to from your different customised projects.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio, you can harness the power of the gradle build system and easily create a solution for your problem. Check out http://tulipemoutarde.be/2013/10/06/gradle-build-variants-for-your-android-project.html